# how to display text in a JSP?text path is stored in a database

Tags: jsp

at first I save the text and image in the database ,and in the front-end i use statement to display the text that in web object:

```
<img src="<%=picturepath %>" width="570" /> 

<jsp:include page="<%=contentpath %>" />
```

then in the back-end ,i restart a web project .I use virtual route: ***D:\site*** .when read the ***a.jpg*** or ***a.txt*** ,I can enter

```
http://localhost:8080/site/a.jpg or
http://localhost:8080/site/a.txt in the IE.
```

then it show.

I upload the image and text on  ***D:\site*** with apache , then save the route    ***txt/site/a.jpg and  /site/a.txt*** in Mysql. and with the statement

```
<img src="<%=picturepath %>" width="570" />
```

the text and image will display

but

```
<jsp:include page="<%=contentpath %>" />
```

this statement can't display the text

I think it's because the ***contentpath*** is relative path,site and the project in same catalogue. my original opinion is

```
http://localhost:8080/site/a.txt
```

but it turn out to be:

```
http://localhost:8080/webapp/site/a.txt
```

I hope to know how to display the ***/site/a.txt*** that read with the datebase in jsp

merci beaucoup

Comment: -1 What is this and what does it supposed to mean? The question is not at all clear as to what you want and what you are doing? Consider elaborating.

Comment: i add the details about the question

Comment: so you want to: 1) Display an image (using `<img>` tag) which is uploaded on the server and for which path is stored in database 2) Display text on the browser, from a text file which is uploaded on the server and for which path is stored in the database. Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please clearly mention what do you want to do.

Comment: the image solved ,so it is 2) text

Comment: I build two web project for front and back,and front and back share same mysql database,the database store the relative path of image ,then build a virtual route,redeploy the front-end ,the image can show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I build two separate web project for front and back,upload the text on the back-end to the frond-end web project: workspace \ webapp.and front and back share same mysql database,the database store the relative path of image ,then build a virtual route,redeploy the front-end ,the image can show,the text doesn't .